# Convert code from C++ to Mathematica

Tags: matrix, syntax, c++

I need to know how to convert the following code in C++ to Mathematica.

```
    for(k=0;k<4;k++){
for(i=1;i<6;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<6;j++) {
        if (Matrix(i,j)==1) {
            auth(i) = auth(i)+hub(j);
        }
    }
}
normalize(auth)
for(i=1;i<6;i++) {
    for(j=0;j<6;j++) {
        if (AdjacencyMatrix(i,j)==1) {
            hub(i) = hub(i)+auth(j);
        }
    }
normalize(hub)
}
```

}

I have written the following code but I am having so much trouble accessing and setting matrix elements.

```
hub = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
auth = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0] // MatrixForm
For[i = 1, i < 5, i++,
 For[j = 1, j < 5, j++,
  If[AMT[[i, j]] == 1,
   auth[[1, i]] = auth[[1, i]] + hub[[j, 1]]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

Comment: Lists are enclosed in curly braces, not square brackets. `MatrixForm` is a display construct. What is `AMT`??

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I believe this is equivalent to `Total@Transpose@amt`, assuming `amt` is a matrix of `0`'s and `1`'s and `hub` is always a constant list of `1`'s.

Answer (score 3):

You are inconsistent with the number of entries in your arrays.  You seem to want 5.

```
mymatrix = Table[RandomInteger[1], {5}, {5}];
hub = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
auth = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
Table[If[mymatrix[[i, j]] == 1, auth[[i]] = auth[[i]] + hub[[j]]], 
  {i, 5}, {j, 5}];
auth
```

or

```
mymatrix = Table[RandomInteger[1], {5}, {5}];
hub = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1};
auth = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
Do[If[mymatrix[[i, j]] == 1, auth[[i]] = auth[[i]] + hub[[j]]], 
  {i, 5}, {j, 5}];
auth
```

Also, as others point out, never use upper-case letters to begin a variable name (e.g., AMT) as it may conflict with *Mathematica's* function names.

@March is correct that for your particular choice of `hub` and `auth` and the assumption that `mymatrix` contains just $0$s and $1$s, then indeed the answer is `Total@Transpose@mymatrix`.  For other conventions, the answers will differ.